# Traceback with getattr()

Tags: python

I call its methods through getattr (module, method_name)
and call these methods are not displayed in the traceback, it is difficult to debug
How to make calls to these methods are displayed in the traceback?

Traceback:

```
File "/home/master/venvs/hello_traversal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/master/djcode/django_traversal_helloworld/traversal/router.py" in route_factory
  117.     return router.resource_tree_traverse()
File "/home/master/djcode/django_traversal_helloworld/traversal/router.py" in resource_tree_traverse
  112.         return self.get_view(view_name, params)
File "/home/master/djcode/django_traversal_helloworld/traversal/router.py" in get_view
  74.                 TFactory = self.get_path(t_factory_path)
File "/home/master/djcode/django_traversal_helloworld/traversal/router.py" in get_path
  45.             m = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
```

but I have called 'post_list_view' method, and it's not in traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided this problem by adding this code:

```
     try:
          exc_info = sys.exc_info()
          ...
     finally:
        # Display the *original* exception in traceback  exclude KeyError
        if exc_info[0]:
            if not isinstance(exc_info[1], KeyError):
                traceback.print_exception(*exc_info)
        del exc_info
```